# there is a problem in the gas requirement

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, wallet

I have been written a smart contract, I am trying to execute the following code but I have these problems:
1- "Gas requirement of function EKM.register_PK is infinite: If the gas requirement of a function is higher than the block gas limit, it cannot be executed. Please avoid loops in your functions or actions that modify large areas of storage (this includes clearing or copying arrays in storage)
Pos: 32:0:"
2- "Use "assert(x)" if you never ever want x to be false, not in any circumstance (apart from a bug in your code). Use "require(x)" if x can be false, due to e.g. invalid input or a failing external component.
more
Pos: 30:2:"
My code:

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.13;
//SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT
contract EKM{
    /**
 * @dev VTA is a state variable
 */
address public VTA;
 /**
   * @dev mapping address as key to struct user with mapping name users
   */
mapping (uint => user) public users;
/**
     * @dev assigning the contract deployer as the  VTA
     */
    constructor() {
       VTA =msg.sender;
       }
        
       
struct user {

string PKname;
string PKvehicle;
uint256 vP; 
bool status;                    
     }
     
  event addPK(string name, string PKv, uint256 VPv) ;  
function register_PK(uint ID_v, string memory PKname, string memory PKvehicle, uint256 vP) public returns(bool){
  require(users[ID_v].status == true,"register the public key of the user");
  if(msg.sender != VTA)
  {revert();}
    if(ID_v == 0)
    {return false;}
    else
    {
         ID_v++;
    users[ID_v]= user(PKname,PKvehicle,vP,true);
   
    //PKname=users[ID_v].PKname;
    //PKvehicle=users[ID_v].PKvehicle;
   // vP=users[ID_v].vP;
      emit addPK(PKname, PKvehicle, vP);
    return true;
    }
   }

}
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Go to solidity static analysis ,and then gas and economy , untick all options except. This on local calls:
Invocation of local functions via 'this' and  Delete dynamic array:
Use require/assert to ensure complete deletion. it will work